# Java Optional.ofNullable with Mockito

Tags: java, java-8, mockito, option-type

Does `java.util` `Optional.ofNullable` works properly with Mockito?

During the code execution I encounter something like this:

```
User user = Optional.ofNullable(userProviderMock.findUser()).orElse(someMethod())
```

I set my mock behaviour like following:

```
when(userProviderMock.findUser()).thenReturn(new User());
```

When I run it, `userProviderMock` returns `new User()` (debug confirms that), but somehow `someMethod()` is still executed.
I have literally no idea why this is happening. Any clues?

Comment: I see no reason for Mockito to be interfering here. You should try and find out what the actual value of the `Optional` is, for example by inspecting its value before calling `orElse`, or debugging into that method.

Comment: When I call `isPresent()` on `Optional`, result is `true`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mockito and `ofNullable` aren't really at issue here. Consider this code:

```
Optional.of("foo").orElse(someMethod())
```

The above code will evaluate to `Optional.of("foo")` — but it still *calls* `orElse`, so it still has to call `someMethod()` in order to pass its return-value as an argument to `orElse`, even though that argument ends up not being used.

If this is a problem for you — if you don't want `someMethod()` to be called unless its return-value is actually needed — then you should use `orElseGet` instead:

```
Optional.of("foo").orElseGet(() -> someMethod())
```

or rather:

```
User user = Optional.ofNullable(userProviderMock.findUser()).orElseGet(() -> someMethod())
```

---

**Edited to add:** [Didier L](https://stackoverflow.com/users/525036/didier-l) points out that `() -> someMethod()` can also be written as `this::someMethod` (that is: we can write it as a method reference rather than a lambda), which is probably more readable.

Either way, it gets converted implicitly to approximately this:

```
User user = Optional.ofNullable(userProviderMock.findUser()).orElseGet(new Supplier<User>() {
    public User get() {
        return someMethod();
    }
});
```

Comment: `someMethod()` is complicated company logic, which I do not want to call unless Optional is empty.
To summarize, difference between `orElse()` and `orElseGet` is that the first one always calls code inside of brackets, no matter if that will be used od not and the second one, only in case when Optional is empty? Right?

Comment: @krzakov: Uh, not quite. There's nothing special about `Optional` -- it's just a library class, it doesn't have any ability to circumvent the normal way that Java code is executed. In particular, `orElse()` doesn't "call" any code; its argument is evaluated *before* `orElse` is called, just as always happens in Java. The difference is that `orElseGet()`, instead of taking a value to use when the Optional is empty, it takes a Supplier that it can call to *get* the value to use when the Optional is empty. So it only calls that Supplier if it has to. Does that make sense?

Comment: You can also write `orElseGet(this::someMethod)` to avoid writing a  lambda.